# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de crear un trigger que actualice una fila y no todas las filas al momento de insertar un registro?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Con un trigger en la tabla `DetalleCompras` quiero actualizar el campo `stock` de una fila particular en la tabla `Productos`.

Tabla `DETALLECOMPRAS`

[image]

En esta tabla inserto la cantidad de productos a comprar en el campo del mismo nombre `CANTIDAD`

Tabla `PRODUCTOS`

[image]

En esta tabla en el campo `STOCK` quiero sumar la cantidad de la tabla `detallecompras` pero, al hacerlo, me suma la cantidad para todas las filas y no, por ejemplo, solo para la fila donde esta `'PANADOL'`.

Tenia una cantidad de 10 en `stock` para cada registro y al hacer dos inserciones de 10 solo para `PANADOL` se sumaron a los otros dos registros, entonces lo que quiero es evitar que se sume para los demás registros y solo lo haga para un solo registro, espero darme a entender.

Mi trigger actual es:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER SumarStock
    AFTER INSERT ON detallecompras 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE productos SET stock= stock + new.cantidad
    WHERE codproducto` = codproducto;
    END;
    $$
```

Comment: Para actualizar una fila agrega un `where` que filtre todo excepto la fila que quieras actualizar. La única manera de actualizar todas las filas es no agregar ningún `where` al `update` o que este `where` no excluya ninguna fila existente.

Comment: DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER SumarStock
AFTER INSERT ON detallecompras 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE productos SET stock= stock + new.cantidad
WHERE codproducto` = codproducto;
END;
$$

Lo he hecho de esa forma pero me actualiza todas las filas y no la que quiero, por ejemplo si en el where pongo 1 como codigo especificando en ese caso si actualiza un campo :( @jachguate

Comment: Alex, por favor edita tu pregunta para agregar esa información. Veo que eres nuevo por aquí, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en la cláusula `where` de la sentencia `update` del *trigger*.

```
WHERE codproducto = codproducto
```

Dado que no calificas los campos, y que solo hay una tabla en la sentencia, esto es equivalente a:

```
WHERE productos.codproducto = productos.codproducto
```

Acá estás pidiendo al motor que, para cada fila de la tabla `productos` compare el valor de la columna `codproducto` consigo mismo. Todas las filas de la tabla, excepto las que tengan `null` en esa columna, cumplirán con esa condición.

Pero lo que tu quieres es comparar el valor del campo `codproducto` en la tabla `productos` con el insertado en la tabla `detallecompras`. Para ello haces referencia al registro que se está insertando con el pseudo registro `New`, que tiene los valores que tomó el registro recién insertado, como ya lo haces para tomar el valor del campo `cantidad`.

```
create trigger SumarStock
after insert on DetalleCompras 
for each row
begin
  update productos 
     set stock= stock + new.cantidad
   where productos.codproducto = new.codproducto;
end;
```

Para evitar ambigüedades, he calificado ambos nombres de campo, así se verá con total claridad cual es mi intención, tanto para un programador, como para el motor.

Estoy asumiendo que el campo en la tabla `DetalleCompras` que hace referencia al producto se llama `codproducto`, pues no se ve en tu pregunta. Si no es así, ajusta tu el código.

Comment: Agradezco totalmente su ayuda, muchísimas gracias.